# Create a program with php that will find the missing number in the series of numbers

Tags: php, loops, numbers, find, sequence

i need help with a question, I need to write code in php that will

- find the missing number in the sequence, regardless of that numbers position in the sequence.
- the numbers will increase but the same amount each time.
- the output must be only the number that was missing from the initial list, not just the list with the number in it (I have worked that out myself).

example number sequence, $sequence = 3, 5, 9, 11, 13
obviously the number 7 is missing, but I don't know how to do the code, im assuming it would use loops, but i wouldn't even know were to start, It must be in PHP

Comment: Good. Please, show your efforts

Comment: Indeed it will use loops, and probably array. That's already a good start. Try getting your list into an array and loop through this array for a beginning.

Comment: You will need some rather fancy logic here, which is probably much too broad for a normal question/answer here. There are algorithms for finding patterns, but most of them will only work on a few types of patterns at most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more simple way to get the missing number(s) from the sequence, the way I see it:

```
<?php
    $sequence = array(3, 5, 9, 11, 13);
    $numbers = array(7, 9, 15);
    $single_nr = 7;
    function getMissingNumber(array $sequence, $single_nr = null, $numbers = array())
    {
        // Check if it exists in the sequence array
        // check single number
        if($single_nr)
        {
            if(!in_array($single_nr, $sequence))
            {
                echo $single_nr . " is not in array" . "<br />";
            }
        }

        // check an array of numbers
        if($numbers)
        {
            foreach($numbers as $nr)
            {
                if(!in_array($nr, $sequence))
                {
                    echo $nr . " is not in array" . "<br />";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    echo getMissingNumber($sequence, null, $numbers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
$str="3,5,9,11,13" ;
$arr=explode(',', $str);
$no=array();
for ($i=3; $i <30 ; $i=$i+2) { 
    $m=$i+2;
    if (!(in_array($m, $arr)))
  {
  $no[]=$m;
  }
    }



    print_r($no);
// OUTPUT- Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 15 )
     ?>
```

Comment: why do you answer these questions?

Comment: @Erdem Ece i dont understand!

Comment: he does not write any code but asking for someone to write his code. this is not a place for freelancers.

Comment: @Erdem Ece i totally agree with you and m sure you are right, but this is only his own loss in not trying to code by himself not mine because his skills wont increase! He asked for a solution and i provided one!

Comment: @sunny  I actually do code, but i'm relatively new to php for this sort of programming, This question was given to me in a job interview (clearly I didn't get the job, I miss understood what they were looking for) but I was looking to work out a solution and learn from the experience so I was looking for people with more experience who would maybe point me in the right direction so I could learn doing it myself, not the full answer.

Comment: @user3506091 you misunderstood me, that wasnt a personal comment meant for you, its about everyone who comes to stackoverflow just for the seek of easy answers so that he doesnt have to code by himself, if what you said is true then no problem but should have mentioned this in your question that you are not seeking for code but you are looking for hint of how to code this! then i am sure evryone around here will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Only uses the first three elements to find the interval (needs a 2 out of 3 match) and doesn't validate if the rest of the sequence follow the rule, but also finds more missing elements:

```
<?php

$sequence = array(3, 5, 9, 13, 15, 17, 21);

// guess
$step = $sequence[1] - $sequence[0];
// validate
if (($sequence[2] - $sequence[1]) != $step) {
    if (($sequence[3] - $sequence[2]) != $step) {
        $step = $sequence[2] - $sequence[1];
        if (($sequence[3] - $sequence[2]) != $step) {
            die('first three intervals are all different');
        }
    }
}

$should = range($sequence[0], $sequence[count($sequence) - 1], $step);
echo 'Missing: ', implode(', ', array_diff($should, $sequence));
```